# Google charts Column Chart, Is it possible to show y axis and bar values in Indian number format?

Tags: google-visualization, number-formatting, column-chart

[image]

In this image y axis values and values above each bars are not in Indian number format, is their any way to change number format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the [`NumberFormat` Class](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#numberformat)

provide the pattern and format the data columns
this will format the annotations and tooltips

```
var formatNumber = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
  pattern: '##,##,##0.000'
});
formatNumber.format(data, 1);
formatNumber.format(data, 2);
```

to format the y-axis, provide the same pattern in the chart options...

```
vAxis: {
  format: '##,##,##0.000'
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Month', 'ByCash', 'ByCard'],
    ['April 2017', 2065937, 0],
    ['May 2017', 1522408, 0],
    ['June 2017', 811576, 750],
  ]);

  var numberPattern = '##,##,##0.000';

  var formatNumber = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    pattern: numberPattern
  });
  formatNumber.format(data, 1);
  formatNumber.format(data, 2);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1, {
    calc: 'stringify',
    sourceColumn: 1,
    type: 'string',
    role: 'annotation'
  }, 2, {
    calc: 'stringify',
    sourceColumn: 2,
    type: 'string',
    role: 'annotation'
  }]);

  var options = {
    annotations: {
      alwaysOutside: true
    },
    colors: ['#00BCD4', '#0097A7'],
    height: 400,
    vAxis: {
      format: numberPattern
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(view, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: hope this helps, i'm not 100% certain on the actual pattern for indian numbers...

Comment: Exactly this is what i need. But i want only integer value so i used "format: '##,##,###' ". Working fine. thank u